# PHP next() not working

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a gallery using PHP. The images load properly, but the next and previous buttons don't seem to work. Clicking next on picture #1 brings you to picture #3 but clicking back on picture #3 bring you to picture #2 which is correct. How should I change my code to make it so both go in order?

```
    <?php
function listPicturesInDir($dir) {
    $dirname = "../pictures/photos/" . $dir . "/";
    $images = glob($dirname . "*.jpg");
    $previousPic = "null";
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $next = next($images);
        $name = str_replace(".jpg", "", $image);
        $fp = strrpos($name, '/', 5) + 1;
        $name = substr($name, $fp, strlen($name));
        $id = str_replace(" ", "", $name);

        echo '<a href="#' . $id . '"><img class="galleryPics" src="' . $image . '" alt = "' . $name . '" title="'. $name.'"/></a>';
        echo '<div id="' . $id . '" class="modalDialog">';
        echo '<div>';
        if($previousPic !== "null"){
            echo'<a href="#'.$previousPic . '"><img src="../pictures/arrowLeft2.png" alt="Previous photograph" title= "Previous photograph" class="arrow"/></a> ';
        }

        if($next !== false){
            $name_next = str_replace(".jpg", "", $next);
            $fp_next = strrpos($name_next, '/', 5) + 1;
            $name_next2 = substr($name_next, $fp_next, strlen($name_next));
            $id_next = str_replace(" ", "", $name_next2);
            echo'<a href="#'.$id_next . '"><img src="../pictures/arrowRight2.png" alt="Next photograph" title="Next photograph" class="arrow"/></a>';
        }
        echo '<a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>';
        echo '<h2>' . $name . '</h2>';
        echo '<img class="modalImg" src="' . $image . '" alt = "' . $name . '"/>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '';
        echo '</div>';
        //echo $next;
        $previousPic = $id;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `next($images)` within a `foreach ($images ...)` statement, thus modifying the internal array pointer. This *may lead to unexpected behavior*, as pointed out in the [documentation on foreach](http://www.php.net/foreach):

> As *foreach* relies on the internal array pointer, changing it within the loop may lead to unexpected behavior.

This illustrates your problem, using `foreach` and `next`:

```
$images = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four');

foreach ($images as $image) {
    $next = next($images);
    echo "$image => $next", PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
one => three
two => four
three => 
four =>
```

One may think that just replacing the `next()` with `current()` would help, but alas:

```
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $next = current($images);
    echo "$image => $next", PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
one => two
two => two
three => two
four => two
```

According to a comment on the `foreach` documentation page, there used to  be a notice on said page stating that:

> Unless the array is referenced, *foreach* operates on a copy of the specified array and not the array itself. *foreach* has some side effects on the array pointer. Don't rely on the array pointer during or after the foreach without resetting it.

Don't know why that was removed, but if we use a reference for `$image` then it actually works (note the `&`):

```
foreach ($images as &$image) {
    $next = current($images);
    echo "$image => $next", PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
one => two
two => three
three => four
four =>
```

But then maybe an old school for loop just makes more sense:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($images); $i++) {
    $nextIndex = $i + 1;
    $next = ($nextIndex < count($images)) ? $images[$nextIndex] : null;
    $image = $images[$i];
    echo "$image => $next", PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
one => two
two => three
three => four
four =>
```

Output from PHP 5.5.20.

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out a while ago but your answer is very good at explaining what the problem is

Answer (score -1):

```
$images = sort(glob($dirname . "*.jpg"));
```